# python: Store all cell values with xlrd and write to new workbook using xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

im trying to copy all cells on a sheet to a new workbook. i can store cell values manually like in the example code below and paste variable in respective cells but i want to automate the collection of cell data. I am very new to python but i can conceptually see something along the line of this but i could use some help to finish it, thanks!

## attempt to automate cell collection

```
 def cell(r,c): 
   set r+=1 
    cellname = c.isalpha() + r
      if r <= sheet.nrow:  
           cellname = (r,c,sheet.cell_value)
```

...... i get lost around here but i assume there should be a sheet.ncols and nrows

## current manual cell copying

```
 cellA1 = sheet.cell_value(0,0)
 cellA2 = sheet.cell_value(1,0)
 cellA3 = sheet.cell_value(2,0)
 cellA4 = sheet.cell_value(3,0)
 cellA5 = sheet.cell_value(4,0)
 cellB1 = sheet.cell_value(0,1)
 cellB2 = sheet.cell_value(1,1)

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
 sheet = workbook.add_sheet('ITEM DETAILS')
```

## manual cell pasting

```
sheet.write(0, 0, cellA1)
sheet.write(1, 0, cellA2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply loop through the cells in the sheet, by using `sheet.nrows` and `sheet.ncols` as the limit to loop up to. Also, make sure you do not define the new worksheet you are creating as `sheet` itself, use a new name. Example:

```
newworkbook = xlwt.Workbook()
newsheet = newworkbook.add_sheet('ITEM DETAILS')
for r in range(sheet.nrows):
    for c in range(sheet.ncols):
        newsheet.write(r, c, sheet.cell_value(r, c))
```

Then use `newsheet` instead of `sheet` wherever you want to use the new sheet.

Comment: you are the best, this definitely answered this question

Answer (score 1):

Anand S Kumar's answer is correct but you need to change `i` to `r` and `j` to `c`.  For extra benefit I added a bit more code for a complete code example.  This code opens an existing excel file, reads all of the data from the first sheet, and writes that same data to a new excel file.

```
    import os,xlrd,xlwt

    if os.path.isfile(outExcel):os.remove(outExcel)#delete file if it exists

    inExcel= (r'C:\yourpath\inFile.xls')
    outExcel= (r'C:\yourpath\outFile.xls')

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(inExcel)
    sheetIn = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheetOut = workbook.add_sheet('DATA')

    for r in range(sheetIn.nrows):
        for c in range(sheetIn.ncols):
            sheetOut.write(r, c, sheetIn.cell_value(r, c))

    workbook.save(outExcel)#save the result
```